# enable checkbox when entering text in other text input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, checkbox

Usually they make another thing: enable/disable text input field when checkbox checked/unchecked, but i need enable group of checkboxes (weekdays) only when user entering some text in text field (Start date). So checkboxes must still disable while user not type Start date in input field.

I think that I need back action than here: http://jsfiddle.net/H8VPY/11/

Please help me choose right jquery event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `prop()` method and `keyup` event handler. Try the following:

```
$('input[name=other_name]').keyup(function(){
    if (this.value.length > 0) {
       $('input[name="others"]').prop('disabled', false)
    } else {
       $('input[name="others"]').prop('disabled', true)      
    }
})
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/H8VPY/47/)

or as Esailija correctly suggests you can use shorter version:

```
$('input[name=other_name]').keyup(function(){
     $('input[name="others"]').prop('disabled', !this.value.length)
})
```

Comment: `$('input[name="others"]').prop('disabled', !this.value.length )` would work as well

Comment: Fantastic, thank you Raminson and Esailija, your answer solved problem.

Now I want to color this text input with red (add some css class) when user try to check checkbox and can't do it 'cause it is disabled. or just hint some message near checkbox.

Or I can't do it because checkbox is disabled and all events will not work with it?

Comment: Thank you again Raminson. I'll add css to <span> and it'll be cool!

Answer (score 0):

add a class and disable to your checkboxes;

```
<checkbox class="checkbox_class" disabled >
```

on your text box;

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="javascript: if($(this).val() != '') $('.checkbox_class').enable()" >
```